# Get UTF-8 character codes from Python unicode string

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-2.6

I'm reading a string from the command line which I know is in Korean encoded as UTF-8. I get the string by running a command like so

```
<my_command> | od -t x1
```

which gives me:

```
0000000 ec a7 80 ec 97 ad 2f ea b5 ad ea b0 80 0a
0000016
```

With the six UTF-8 characters being `{eca780}{ec97ad}{2f}{eab5ad}{eab080}{0a}` and then I read it in Python using

```
utf8_str = unicode(text_from_the_cl, encoding='utf-8')
```

What I just want to do is to be able to see the string I've read in terms of the UTF-8 codes for the characters that I've read. So something like `\uc9c0\uc5ed/\uad6d\uac00` would be good. This is just to check that they are being read in properly.

(*I should point out also that this is Python 2.6.x - over which I have no control*)

Comment: Sorry, what is your question exactly? You can verify the value with `print repr(utf8_str)`; is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify the contents of your `unicode` string, use the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> unhexlify(''.join('ec a7 80 ec 97 ad 2f ea b5 ad ea b0 80 0a'.split()))
'\xec\xa7\x80\xec\x97\xad/\xea\xb5\xad\xea\xb0\x80\n'
>>> print unhexlify(''.join('ec a7 80 ec 97 ad 2f ea b5 ad ea b0 80 0a'.split())).decode('utf8')
지역/국가

>>> print repr(unhexlify(''.join('ec a7 80 ec 97 ad 2f ea b5 ad ea b0 80 0a'.split())).decode('utf8'))
u'\uc9c0\uc5ed/\uad6d\uac00\n'
```

The `repr()` result for a `unicode` value uses `\uhhhh` escape sequences for non-ASCII and non-Latin1 codepoints; for Latin 1 codepoints and for non-printable characters, `\xhh` escape sequences are used.

Comment: Thanks that did it. I had to use `print (repr(utf8_str))` to avoid a syntax error.

Comment: @Component10: You are using Python 2.6; you shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `encode` method:

```
utf8_str.encode('utf8')
```

Note that `utf8_str` isn't a great name for the variable. The original byte sequence uses UTF-8 encoding to represent the Unicode characters; the call to `unicode` "decodes" them into the actual Unicode code points. To get the bytes back, you just re-encode the code points to UTF-8.